# Error when clicking Add-button in CRUD

Tags: atk4

When a form or an add-button returns to a page, it throws an error or shows wrong output on the page, if there is js or other kinds of output on the page. Here is an example:

```
    $tabs->addTab('Skoler')->add('CRUD')->setModel('School');
    $crud=$tabs->addTab('Elever')->add('CRUD');
    $crud->setModel($student);
    if($crud->grid){
      $crud->grid->addButton('addStudents')->set('Importer elever')->js('click',$this->js()->univ()
       ->dialogURL('Importer elever',$this->api->url('importusers&usertype=student'))
       ->execute());;
      $crud->grid->js(true)->addClass('reloadstudent');
      $crud->grid->js('.reloadstudent')->reload();
    }
```

When clicking on "Add School" This outputs

```
$('#barometeradmin_mgr').univ().dialogURL('Importer elever','/redskab/barometer/admin/?page=importusers\x26usertype=student\x26barometeradmin_mgr_tabs_view_htmlelement_crud_virtualpage=add')
```

in the dialogurl created by the button.

Is there a way to check if the page is loaded for the second time (that is, by the button).

Thanks!
Jeppe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need to do is leave out the '->execute()'?